# How do I backup my Minecraft Bedrock Edition worlds without an SD card or a computer?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I really need to back up my worlds. I've lost them multiple times to different reasons and I'm sure it could happen again. Every where I go it says something like, "Oh just go into your SD card!", or, "Plug your device into your computer or laptop!"; the problem is I don't have either of those.

Is there a way I could do this with JUST my phone and my file explorer?

Oh and another thing.
When I go into the minecraftWorlds  folder there is nothing in there other than resource packs and some other unrecognizable stuff.[image]

Comment: All of that unrecognizable stuff together *is* the world data. There's not just one file that has the world, it's all of that stuff. Assuming that 2SwmXcjMAAA= is the name of your world, I would suggest making a copy of that entire folder and  putting it somewhere else. I'm not sure if that's how to do it on Bedrock, but it works on Java so I assume it would work similarly on Bedrock.

Comment: I believe specifically the `level.dat` is the main piece, but it would be best to just copy everything.  Upload it to Google Drive, maybe? Or Dropbox?

Comment: Whether you can back it up reliably depends on how you're losing your world.  If you need to reinstall Minecraft, only your tablet should do.  If you have to wipe your tablet, you need something external.